# Network Connection Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, connection

How to get the best possible http connection in an blackberry application? I use the Network Diagnostic tool provided by RIM but most of the time it fails to find any connection while other applications are connected to the internet without a problem.

Is there any other way to find out how to connect to internet?

Answer (score 1):

Try
http://www.versatilemonkey.com/HttpConnectionFactory.java

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had created something to help myself out for the same purpose.. I hope it would be useful for you too.. Check it out at http://www.sameernafdey.com/2009/08/httpconnection-over-bis-wap-10-11-wap.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @imMobile I have a library you can try as well [here](http://dftr.ca/?p=273). It is very simple to use.
The HttpRequest should handle all the service book and coverage/transport stuff for you.